# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\log(\log(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x))) \cdot \log(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x)))}{\tan(2x)} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation

> $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\log(\log(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x))) \cdot \log(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x)))}{\tan(2x)} \,dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\log(\log(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x))) \cdot \log(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x))}{\tan(2x)} \,dx = -\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \log(-\log(\tan x)) \cdot \log(\tan x) \cdot \tan(2x) \,dx$$

$$= -2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\log(-\log(\tan x)) \cdot \log(\tan x) \cdot \tan x}{1-\tan^2 x} \,dx \Bigg|_{\tan x=e^{-t}}$$

$$= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t \cdot \log(t \cdot e^{-2t})}{1 - e^{-4t}} \,dt = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} t \cdot \log(t \cdot e^{-(4n+2)t}) \,dt$$

$$= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} L \cdot (t \cdot \log(t)) \cdot (4n + 2)$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @KurtG. How to go further or a better way to approach?

Comment: What is that $L\,?$ Not that I am *that* interested. If I were you I would check my formulas numerically. If they pass I hand in that solution and do something more interesting.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}I=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\ln\left(\ln\left(\tan\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)\right)\cdot\ln\left(\tan\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)}{\tan\left(2x\right)}dx\\
=&-\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left(\ln\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)\right)\cdot\ln\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)\tan\left(2x\right)dx\\
=&\int_{1}^{+\infty}\ln\left(\ln\left(t\right)\right)\ln\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{2t}{t^{4}-1}dt\\
=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(s\right)s\frac{2e^{2s}}{e^{4s}-1}ds\end{align}$$
Using the Feymann's trick:
$$f(z):=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{z}\frac{2e^{2s}}{e^{4s}-1}ds$$
$$f(z)=(2^{-z} - 2^{-2z - 1}) \zeta(1 + z) \Gamma(1 + z)$$
$$I=f'(1)$$
$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{48}\left(3 + \ln(2) + 3 \ln(\pi)-36 \ln(A)\right)\approx -0.375831$$

Where:

- $\zeta(z)$ is the zeta Riemann function
- $\Gamma(z)$ is the Gamma function
- $A$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin Constant